# I get ER_PARSE_ERROR when trying to CREATE a TABLE with PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, popsql

I'm learning SQL and from time to time I get this error: `ER_PARSE_ERROR`.
For example:

```
`CREATE TABLE branch_supplier(
    branch_id INT,
    supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
    suply_type INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE SET CASCADE
);`
```

What I get wrong is the '`);`'

I tried to rewrite the code, and restart the PopSQL program but non of them worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `set` keyword :

```
CREATE TABLE branch_supplier(
    branch_id INT,
    supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
    suply_type INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```